# Pass a variable from one PHP file to another via $.post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, post

I have a contact form that passes the data via jQuery `$.post`.

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    $("#contact_form").submit(function (a) {
        a.preventDefault();
        $.post("<?php echo home_url('/_asset/contact.php'); ?>", {
            contact_name    :   $("#contact_name").val(),
            contact_email   :   $("#contact_email").val(),
            contact_subject :   $("input:radio[name=subject]:checked").val(),
            contact_textarea:   $("#contact_textarea").val(),
            contact_postid  :   $("#contact_postid").val(),
        }, function (a) {
            $("div#response").removeClass("hidden");
            $("div#response").delay(1E3).html(a);
        });
    });
});
```

**contact.php**

```
$contact_name = $_POST['contact_name'];
$contact_email = $_POST['contact_email'];
$contact_subject = $_POST['contact_subject'];
$contact_message = $_POST["contact_textarea"];
$contact_postid = $_POST['contact_postid'];
$contact_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if( empty($contact_name) && empty($contact_email) && empty($contact_subject) && empty($contact_message) ) {
    die('You must fill out all fields amigo!');
}

// Build that email boy!
if( !empty($contact_postid) ) { $email_id = ' (' . $contact_postid . ')'; }
$email_to        =  'email@example.com';
$email_subject   =  'Contact Form: ' . $contact_subject . $email_id;

$email_header    =  'From: ' . $contact_name . '<' . $contact_email . '>' . "\r\n";
$email_header   .=  'Reply-To:' . $contact_email . "\r\n";
$email_header   .=  'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$email_message   =  nl2br($contact_message);

// Try sending the email
if(!mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $email_header)){
    $status = 'red';
    die('Error sending email.');
} else {
    $status = 'green';
    die('Email sent!');
}
```

**PHP form**

```
<div class="respond_form">
<form method="post" id="contact_form">
    <h2>Let's get contacting!</h2>
    <div id="response" class="hidden alert <?php echo $status; ?>"></div>

    <div class="line">
        <label for="contact_name" title="Please enter your name (required)">Your name <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="contact_name" id="contact_name" tabindex="1" placeholder="John Smith" required="required"/>
    </div>

    <div class="line">
        <label for="contact_email" title="Please enter your email (required)">Your email (so we can contact you) <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="email" name="contact_email" id="contact_email" tabindex="2" placeholder="mail@example.com" required="required"/>
    </div>


    <?php if( isset($_GET['subject']) ) { ?>
        <input hidden="hidden" name="subject" type="radio" value="<?php echo $_GET['subject']; ?>" checked="checked">
        <?php if( isset($_GET['PostID']) ) { echo '<input hidden="hidden" id="contact_postid" name="postid" type="input" value="' . $_GET['PostID'] . '">'; } ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="line">
            <label>What is the message in regards to? <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <ul style="list-style:none; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                <label style="font-weight:normal;"><input style="margin-right: 10px;" name="subject" type="radio" value="Advertising"<?php if( $_GET['subject'] == 'advertising' ) { echo ' checked="checked"'; } ?>>Advertising</label>
                <label style="font-weight:normal;"><input style="margin-right: 10px;" name="subject" type="radio" value="Contribute an Article"<?php if( $_GET['subject'] == 'contribute' ) { echo ' checked="checked"'; } ?>>Contribute an Article</label>             
            </ul>
        </div>
    <?php } ?> 

    <div class="line">
        <label for="contact_textarea" title="Briefly explain your message (required)">Briefly explain your message <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <textarea name="contact_textarea" id="contact_textarea" rows="10" tabindex="3" maxlength="500" required="required"></textarea>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" id="contact_send" name="contact_send" class="button glow" value="Send Message"/>

</form>
</div>
```

As you can see, I've tried setting a `$status` in the `mail()` function but that didn't work. I'm not entirely sure what's going on with the whole thing (found it ages ago and just built around it) but I know the `die()` message emits into the `div#response`.

Effectively I was hoping to add a class to the `div#response` if the email was successful or not.

**OH!** and incase someone wants to comment on the lack of security, or checking of `$_POST` data, I've stripped it for here :]

Comment: Can you provide more detail on what's going wrong than "it doesn't work"?  Where do things fail?  Does the code produce an error message?  Are the values of your variables what you expect them to be?

Comment: what are you expecting `$status` to do? You call `die()` right after you set it so it is never used for anything

Comment: Your check to see if all fields have been filled out actually just tests if there's at least one field that's been filled out. You should use `||` instead of `&&`.

Comment: @ASGM sorry forgot to add the form! There aren't any "it doesn't work" I'm asking, like it says in the main question how to pass a variable from one PHP file to another. Meaning, like the second last paragraph I want to get the variable `$status` from contact.php to the PHP form.

Comment: @charlietfl hoping to get the `$status` to echo out into the form. See the `div#response` in the PHP Form.

Comment: @Arjan Like I said I have omitted a lot of the checking because this is NOT about the validity of the form but passing variables!

Comment: `$status` doesn't exist when form gets output from another file... you would need to use session to store status if you need it when form first loads. Easy to change when ajax response returns, check value returned and adjust class accordingly with jQuery

Comment: @charlietfl Mmm I was hoping there was another way. But you seem right in the way to go! Thanks.

Comment: @Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhdfgbv I know, that's why I don't comment about code that's not posted. I just wanted to inform you about something that could be overlooked easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.post sends the data to contact.php and loads its response.

In your case, the response is text that can be "Error sending email." or "Email sent!" (from what you posted) so you just need to test the value and add the related class.

```
$(function () {
    $("#contact_form").submit(function (a) {
        a.preventDefault();
        $.post("<?php echo home_url('/_asset/contact.php'); ?>", {
            contact_name    :   $("#contact_name").val(),
            contact_email   :   $("#contact_email").val(),
            contact_subject :   $("input:radio[name=subject]:checked").val(),
            contact_textarea:   $("#contact_textarea").val(),
            contact_postid  :   $("#contact_postid").val(),
        }, function (a) {
            $("div#response").removeClass("hidden").addClass( (a=="Email sent!") ? "email-success" : "email-error" );
            $("div#response").delay(1E3).html(a);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This works only it adds both classes. Okay let me explain. I've stripped the validation checking for empty fields, and malicious `<script>` tags in the form. If a field is empty, it passes through as your `email-error` class. Then if I successfully fill out the form, it then adds `email-success`, only it doesn't style the div properly. Any way to `addClass().removeClass()` to get it to toggle?

Comment: Also thank you for actually reading the question and answering *it* rather than other sections of the code.

Comment: totally answered my own dilemma! I changed your code to: `toggleClass( (a=="Email sent!") ? "email-error" : "" );` added the classes `email-error email-success` to the DIV and bingo! Unless there's a better way?